# How do I address the upper 16 bits of a 32-bit register?

Tags: assembly

in ASM 32bit there is the EAX register from 0 until 31 bit.
In the EAX there is an AX from 0 bit until 15bit.
How called the register from 15bit until 31bit?

http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/asm_images/eax.png

Comment: There isn't one. The upper 16-bit of a 32-bit register don't have a corresponding register.

Comment: Shift to lower bits, modify, then return to higher. Lower bits are accessible as 16/8 bit value to have 16 and 8 bit registers, and higher part is only extension to 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot address the top 16-bits of a 32-bit register directly.

If you want to fiddle with the top 16 bits without affecting the lower 16 bits, you'll have to use multiple instructions:
You either use masking (`or`/`and`/`xor`) or shifting (`shr`/`shl`).

All the below examples leave the lower 16 bits of `eax` unchanged.

for example:

```
and eax,0x0000FFFF  ; zero out top 16 bits ;and with 1 does not change bit.
or eax,0xFFFF0000   ; set top 16 bits to 1; or with 0 does not change bit.
xor eax,0xFFFF0000  ; invert top 16 bits; xor with 0 does not change bit.

;copy ax into eax-high
mov ebx,eax         ; copy eax to temp register
movzx eax,ax        ; clear out top 16 bits of eax
shl ebx,16          ; move ax to ebx-high
or eax,ebx          ; combine ax and ebx-high, cloning ax.

;exchange ax and eax-high
rol eax,16
```

You can lookup the descriptions of the instructions here: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/

Comment: Also useful: BMI2 `rorx ecx, eax, 16` to copy-and-rotate.  Or `shld ecx, eax, 16` to double-shift into `ecx`, with a dependency on the old value of ecx.

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot access the high order byte directly, there is an instruction that makes this much easier than the logic in the other answer.

Look into the `BSWAP` instruction.  This instruction swaps the bytes in the 32 bit register, allowing you to then access the pieces using `AH` and `AL` or just `AX`.  You must be aware that BSWAP reverses the order of the bytes, so it is not simply swapping the high order and low order words.

```
 mov eax, [ebx]
 bswap eax  ; The highest order byte is now in AL
            ; The second highest order byte is now in AH
```

Comment: `bswap` also swaps the bytes around, how is this helpful? Now you've got your data in the wrong endianness.

Comment: If you read the answer you'll see that I pointed that out.  If the ultimate goal is to access the individual bytes in the word, this is extremely useful.

Comment: It's one bye shorter than `rol eax,16` ([embedding the register in the opcode](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/BSWAP.html)), and it's the same performance on most CPUs.  Maybe running on a different port.  It doesn't have an immediate operand, which could be an advantage for the uop cache depending on surrounding instructions having immediates + disp8 or disp32 addressing modes.

Comment: @Johan just do `xchg ah, al` after `bswap` to get higher 16-bit value you want